# Code to check the RTMP and Non- RTMP url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rtmp

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media///bbb-360p.mp4"];

NSURL *URL =[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQRvYYoV6bc"];
```

I have two URLs. I want to frame a condition to check whether the provided URL is RTMP URL OR not.

Comment: Please, provide your error with the code you have done. Otherwise stackoverflow is not the place where people are doing the tasks for you for free.

Comment: They are both http. Rtmp begins with rtmp://

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using NSURL `hostname`,

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media///bbb-360p.mp4"];
```

`url.host` will return `www.rmp-streaming.com`

for this url,

```
NSURL *URL =[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQRvYYoV6bc"];
```

`url.host` will return `www.youtube.com`

Now you can decide what you want. Code not tested, this is just suggestion.